A story where the English professor failed Shakespeare (brought forward in time) in his class
I recall this short story that I must have read about 20 years ago.  An English professor was talking with a professor in another department, wishing that he could meet Shakespeare.  The other chimed in that he had and had failed him in his class, as they had brought him forward in time.
Any ideas anyone?

This is The Immortal Bard by Asimov:

The physics professor, Dr. Phineas Welch, has gotten himself slightly drunk and begins speaking with Scott Robertson, a young English teacher. Welch announces, "I can bring back the spirits of the illustrious dead." [...] "So," he continues, "I tried Shakespeare." [...]
Eventually, Welch says, he enrolled Shakespeare in a night school class on Shakespeare's plays—taught, as it happens, by Robertson. At this point, Robertson begins to become genuinely worried. He recalls a bald man with an unusual accent, and starts to doubt whether Welch's story was all alcoholic fantasy. Timidly, he asks Welch what happened, and the physicist explodes with anger. Shakespeare had been humiliated, he says, and Welch had to send him back to 1600: "You poor simpleton, you flunked him!"

(Previously answered here)
